# Cannot roll back session in auto-commit mode with Slick

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

```
import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver
private val postgres = PostgresDriver.simple.Database.forURL(url, driver = driver)


def myMethod(testCode: Session => Any) {
  val session = postgres.createSession()

  session.conn.setAutoCommit(false)
  try {
  testCode(session)
  } finally {
  session.rollback()
  session.close()
}
```

sbt has following dependencies

```
"com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "2.1.0",
"com.github.tminglei" %% "slick-pg" % "0.6.3"
```

Though I have set autocomit to false I get following. I must be missing something?

```
scala.slick.SlickException: Cannot roll back session in auto-commit mode
at scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.rollback(JdbcBackend.scala:415)
at mycompany.tests.DatabaseSpec$class.withSession(DatabaseSpec.scala:29)
```

API that's using myMethod has

```
tableQuery.insertOrUpdate(tableRow)
```

above error specific to postgres driver and `insertOrUpdate`? if I use `insert` API it rolls back fine with no issue. is there a

Comment: I don't think this is something regarding slick, it looks like more [regarding Postgres](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Autocommit-off-commits-rollbacks-td3556503.html).

Answer (score 1):

the session.rollback() implementation in Slick is

```
def rollback() {
  if(conn.getAutoCommit) throw new SlickException("Cannot roll back session in auto-commit mode")
  doRollback = true
}
```

Seems like your connections stays in auto commit mode for some reason. Slick doesn't seem to be the cause.

Comment: I should have put up more code in the post, which is there now. this appears to be coming from https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/b7b90a98f726a1b680108c4bf1bbc252a0995703/src/main/scala/scala/slick/jdbc/JdbcBackend.scala#L475

Comment: I know nothing about Scala or Slick, but it seems odd to me that you put the `session.conn` into autocommit, but then rollback the `session` not the `session.conn`.  Are you sure there is only one connection involved here and not several?

Comment: Session is a Slick wrapper around a JDBC Connection, which is stored in session.conn. So yes, one connection.