# session withTransaction rollback issue

Tags: scala, slick

```
def withSession(testCode: Session => Any)(implicit db : scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple.Database ) {

    val session = db.createSession()
    session.conn.setAutoCommit(false)
    try {
      testCode(session)
    } finally {
      session.rollback()
      session.close()
    }
}
```

above fixture is created to test database code and rollback after end of the test.
Test looks as below

```
test("insert a row into employee table") {
    withSession { implicit session =>
     val emp = EmployeeRow(-1, Option(1),
          "TestEmployee",Option(1), Option("abc"), None) 

      EmployeeService.save(emp)
    }    

}
```

where `EmployeeService.save()` is

```
 def save(emp: EmployeeRow)(implicit session : Session): EmployeeRow = session.withTransaction{
 (employee returning employee) += emp
}
```

note save() method in there is minimal right now, which will have interaction with other service APIs in there, hence `session.withTransaction` is required to bundle all work within `save()` into single unit of work.

since I am using `session.withTransaction` and `withSession` fixture tries to rollback `session` in `finally` block, it throws

```
scala.slick.SlickException: Cannot roll back session in auto-commit mode
at scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.rollback(JdbcBackend.scala:415)
at com.company.core.tests.DatabaseSpec$class.withSession(DatabaseSpec.scala:25)
at
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot roll back session in auto-commit mode with Slick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25674987/cannot-roll-back-session-in-auto-commit-mode-with-slick)

Comment: @cvogt :it appears in both the cases (my previous post you linked in your comment and this post) it's caused by https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/b7b90a98f726a1b680108c4bf1bbc252a0995703/src/main/scala/scala/slick/jdbc/JdbcBackend.scala#L475 . is there any way to execute a rollback, after each test runs, and still use `withTransaction` ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. withTransaction checks if you are already inside of a transaction and in that case does nothing. Use another withTransaction block in your test code instead of manually setting autocommit and you should be fine.

If it is still not working, consider opening a ticket: https://github.com/slick/slick/issues